# Change the ith element of a QStringList

Tags: replace, qt5, qstring

I am searching solution for half hour and no progress.

Consider the list

```
QStringList foo = {};
for (int i=1; i<8; i++){
    foo << "0";
}
```

If some check box was clicked, I'd like to change the value of the list to `"1"`.

So, for example, how to change the 3rd `0` by `1`? Something like (pseudo code) `foo.replace(3,"0","1")`.

Comment: What about `foo[3] = "1";`?

Comment: @Zim, thanks so much. It is so simple solution. Why didn't I guess it? Why people don't refer to this on other posts? They talk about `replace` and others... also this should be in documentation: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstringlist.html

Comment: If you wish, consider posting and answer and I'll be glad to accept it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just apply the [KISS principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_principle) ;)

```
foo[3] = "1";
```

Comment: I cannot find a SINGLE piece of Qt documentation that says this is how you actually do it

Answer (score 0):

I came across this thread with a similar issue, except the list was passed by reference so this option didn't work.

This line did work:

```
list->operator [](idx) = "val";
```

The `operator` function returns a modifiable instance at `idx` so you can call other functions of the type returned as well:

```
list->operator [](idx).prepend("val");
```

Credit to: https://blog.fearcat.in/a?ID=01500-adf1c894-647c-4d9c-9355-338be961e5df